# NTLM авторизация в Active Directory через PHP под Nginx

Tags: авторизация, ntlm, php, nginx

Как организовать NTLM авторизацию в домене через PHP, при этом не спрашивая у пользователя его данные.

Comment: Абсолютно с вами не согласен, это умеет делать ASP.NET на IIS, также это умеет делать Sharepoint. С этим точно работают браузеры IE и FF, возможно работает Opera. На похожем принципе работают шлюзы во многих корпоративных сетях (хотя возможно на несколько отличающемся способе). Более того технология точнее называется NTLM over HTTP.
Я бы не спрашивал не зная что это возможно в принципе. Единственное что мне пока не удалось находится в моем вопросе.

Comment: Хм, да, был не прав… Копнул сейчас поглубже в Майкрософтовские описания. Сейчас практически все браузеры поддерживают эту фишку. Только тут ситуация вот какая: авторизация-то происходит на уровне протокола HTTP, стало быть, ею занимается веб-сервер, а не Ваш PHP-скрипт. Так что это, видимо, вопрос по настройка веб-сервера.

Comment: Не согласен. В ASP.NET можно реализовать авторизацию своими руками т.е. в поверх веб-сервера.
Кроме того авторизация через куки, например, тоже задействует протокол HTTP, но обычно же не веб-сервер лезет в базу за проверкой а PHP скрипт.

Comment: Скорее всего, это связано с тем, что IIS делегирует проверку подлинности выбранному скрипту. Если Вы это будете использовать только с IIS, то проблем никаких не будет. Но если попытаться эту же штуку развернуть под Апачем, можно нарваться на неприятности.

Comment: Я так не думаю в источниках где я это читал написано что средствами ASP.NET просто создается слой для авторизации т.н. серверно-независимая структура.

Насчет серверной авторизации есть средства для apache вроде бы mod_ntlm, однако мне не понятно как с ним работать из PHP.

И у меня сервер не apache а nginx и очень не хочется менять его, поэтому это одна из причин почему ищу способ сделать это через PHP.

Comment: Я разработкой под ASP\IIS интересовался уже очень давно, так что не уверен… но у меня, всё же, есть ощущение, что это именно фича сервера — пнуть тот самый слой авторизации. Вот нашёл, кстати, фичреквест о добавлении AD-авторизации в nginx: http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/157629

Comment: На офф-сайте nginx нету соответствующего модуля, также я спрашивал у разработчика по почте об этом, он ответил что возможно появится.

Насчет топика - к сожалению там именно реквест и ответ на него касается apache.

Comment: Там вообще нет ответа :). Это тот же автор вопроса просто приводит ссылки на соответствующие модули от Апача, чтобы, если кто-то возьмётся за разработку, им было проще.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nginx не поддерживает авторизацию в AD. [Вот](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/157629) есть фичреквест, но он, вроде как, заглох…

Соответственно, Вам надо делегировать авторизацию своему скрипту. [Вот здесь учат](http://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,18552,20302), как это сделать. Остаётся только подключиться из пхп-скрипта к серверу AD, например, [так](http://phpad.sunyday.net/) или любой ldap-библиотечкой.

Comment: Не нашел как делегировать авторизацию скрипту.

Comment: http://www.opennet.ru/base/net/nginx_x_accel_redirect.txt.html

Comment: Ох, только, боюсь, тут Вы опять упрётесь в невозможность авторизовать человека, теперь уже на уровне пхп… Поскольку Вам же надо будет этим php-скриптом произвести http-авторизацию (чтобы браузер догадался отправить AD-credentials). А эту http-авторизацию опять должен произвести веб-сервер! В таком случае Вас спасёт только поднятие отдельного веб-сервера (например, Апача) специально для проведения этой авторизации.

Answer (score 0):

А есть вот так? О_о

```
$headers = apache_request_headers();     // получаем все заголовки клиента
if (!isset($headers['Authorization'])) { // если заголовка авторизации нет
  header('HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized');   // требуем от клиента авторизации
  header('WWW-Authenticate: NTLM');      // тип требуемой авторизации - NTLM
  exit;                                  // завершаем выполнение скрипта
}
// заголовок авторизации от клиента пришёл
if (substr($headers['Authorization'],0,5) == 'NTLM ') { // проверяем, что это NTLM-аутентификация

  $chain = base64_decode(substr($headers['Authorization'],5)); // получаем декодированное значение
  switch (ord($chain{8})) { // смотрим номер этапа процесса идентификации
    case 3: // этап 5 - приём сообщения type-3
      foreach (array('LM_resp','NT_resp','domain','user','host') as $k=>$v) {
        extract(unpack('vlength/voffset',substr($chain,$k*8+14,4)));
        $val = substr($chain,$offset,$length);
        echo "$v: ".($k<2 ? hex_dump($val) : iconv('UTF-16LE','CP1251',$val))."<br>\r\n";
      }
      exit;
    case 1: // этап 3 (тут было == 0xB2, я исправил на 130). 178 -> B2 или 130 -> 82
        // 0x82 возвращают мозилла и опера при обычном вводе руками, а 0xB2 возвращает IE при параметре "исользовать текущие логин и пароль"
      if (ord($chain{13}) == 0x82||ord($chain{13}) == 0xB2) { // проверяем признак NTLM 0x82 по смещению 13 в сообщении type-1:
        $chain = "NTLMSSP\x00".// протокол
                 "\x02" /* номер этапа */ ."\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00".
                 "\x28\x00" /* общая длина сообщения */ ."\x00\x00".
                 "\x01\x82" /* признак */ ."\x00\x00".
                 "\x00\x02\x02\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00". // nonce
                 "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00";
        header('HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized');
        header('WWW-Authenticate: NTLM '.base64_encode($chain)); // отправляем сообщение type-2
        exit;
      }
  }
}

function hex_dump($str){ // вспомогательная функция, возвращает шестнадцатеричный дамп строки
  return substr(preg_replace('#.#se','sprintf("%02x ",ord("$0"))',$str),0,-1);
}
?>
```

Ваш интернет-обозреватель или используемый прокси-сервер несовместим с NTLM, используйте IE... Спасибо

Comment: если честно там порой забавно, например пока отлаживал этот скрипт на какой то фазе мелькало даже имя моей рабочей группы workgroup в выводе на экран, но в итоге (домена то у меня нету) дает пустую строку, далее имя и имя компьютера как положено

Comment: фурс антон спасибо.
php код рабочий, спас много моего времени. Главное оно корректно работает с русскими фамилия из домена

Comment: фурс антон спасибо. Представленный код реально помог.