# Прозрачная передача логина профиля Windows на squid

Tags: squid

Как сделать прозрачную передачу логина профиля Windows на squid, для последующего сравнения с данными из локального файла?

Задача сделать прозрачную авторизацию на сквиде, но с передачей только имени пользователя (как например ntlm_auth) (ну как бы псевдоавторизацию).
То есть браузер пароль не спрашивает, но отправляет на сквид имя пользователя (логин профиля windows).
Обычная NTLM авторизация работает, но не устраивает по загрузке железки (порядка 2000 пользователей) . Пользователи время от времени получают отказ в обслуживании.
Появилась идея на основе external helper сделать проверку локально на сервере сквида, но там нужно получить %LOGIN, а оно заполняется из существующих схем авторизаций (basic - спрашивает пароль (не подходит) NTLM - ну понятно, авторизирует и тогда дальше нет смысла городить огород (не подходит в виду нагрузки))
Накопал в интернете скрипт ntlm_fake_auth.pl, который позволяет получить прозрачно логин не проводя авторизации, но он (я так понял) недоточен и обрывается на втором этапе NTLM авторизации, на котором логин ещё не передаётся.

Простите за длинную преамбулу
Вопрос:
Как сделать прозрачную передачу логина профиля Windows на свид, для последующего сравнения с данными из локального файла?
Спасибо.

Comment: способов есть несколько, но: с каким локальным файлом сравнивать? конкретики маловато...

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Comment: Вот попробовал объяснить подробнее (поправил вопрос)

Comment: то есть вопрос не в том с каким файлом сравнивать (например это файл с логинами пользователей которым разрешен доступ к инету), а как прозрачно (не спрашивая браузером логин/пароль как basic авторизация) передать прозрачно (как ntlm) логин (логин залогинившегося пользователя в windows например ПК в домене а логин/пас он вводит при логине в систему) Ну а дальше (это уже не вопрос) сверить только этот логин с содержимым лок файла регекспом.

Comment: Я squid не знаю, но могу показать какие пакеты нужно передать, что бы авторизация прошла. Авторизация идёт так  Q1 -> A1(401), Q2+info -> A2 (401), Q3+login -> A3(200 ОК). Т.е. вам нужно грубо говоря отправить с сервера клиенту два пакета, A1 и A2. эти два пакета могут быть константами. Присылая пакет Q3 - браузер передаёт логин в открытом виде, а пароль в закрытом. Т.е. логин проверить - не проблема. А да, вот они http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/105450/17974